# Exporting rendered raster image from graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, raster, export, qgis-modeler

I am new to using the graphical modeler and am trying to export the result raster from my model as a rendered image.

Basically trying to replicate what happens by doing the following to the result raster that shows up in my project layers after I run the model, but would like to automate in the graphical modeler:

right click on raster
export
save as
output mode = 'Rendered image'
filepath  = "............./xxx.tif"